# Java exception handling - catching superclass exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a question on handling exception in web application. Often I hear catching the super class Exception is a bad idea.

Often I write codes to catch all exceptions in struts action / java servlet classes.

```
try {
     // call business facade
     // business facade calls DAO
     // any exception from DAO bubbles up 
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("error", e);
}
```

If we do not catch superclass Exception. How do we handle any unexpected runtime errors and logged them appropriately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [setup a `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) for your project to deal with uncaught exceptions. For example, this is a piece of code that I have in one of my projects:

```
private static void setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    try {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                logger.error("Uncaught Exception detected in thread {}", t, e);
            }
        });
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        logger.error("Could not set the Default Uncaught Exception Handler", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about projects which are written in older versions of java?

Comment: @optimus This has been available since 1.5. For older versions, you'll have to find another way (1.4 has been EOL for more than 4 years now...).

Comment: @assylias: Where does configuration related to this handler go? Any example write-ups?

Comment: @Nambari You want the code to be run as early as possible - For example, you can call the method above from a static block in the main class. Not sure how that applies in the context of a web application though.

Comment: @assylias: I see. I understood how to use this mechanism in standalone, but trying to figure out how it can be used in web application. May be global errors section of framework helps. Need to do some reading on that.

Comment: Any web framework / server worth it's salt is going to handle exceptions uncaught by the webapp, and not allow them to bubble up to the top of the Thread. So it seems like the uncaughtExceptionHandler would never run.

Comment: @mattb To be honest I had not realised the question was in the context of a web app and am not very familiar with them.

Answer (score 2):

In a web application, and in the code snippet you posted, how are you handling the root `Exception`? It looks like you catch it, log it, and move on.

In 99% of cases in a webapp, it would be better to allow the Exception to bubble up to the configured `<error-page>` in your web.xml.

It seems unlikely to me that if you catch an unknown error when "calling the business facade" that it's best for your application to keep trucking on with the rest of it's logic.

Comment: if it bubbles up to the configured <error-page> it only hides the stacktrace from the users. For us, we are interested in informing users the transaction did not complete and log down the exception

Answer (score 1):

Add multiple catch blocks and leave Exception catch as last one.

```
try {
     // call business facade
     // business facade calls DAO
     // any exception from DAO bubbles up 
} catch(SuperClassException se)
{
//Do what you want to do when this exception happens.
}catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("error", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code inside try mostly specifies and flags you about the checked exception which can be caught. Also, looking the codes inside try you can intuit the scenarios for failing case and accordingly unchecked/run-time exception catch block can be added.