# Using Anonymous thread for catching Exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, checked-exceptions

I asked around regarding catching checked exceptions in the context of a thread; the accepted answer was to use `Callable`s and `Future`s.

But I realized that I can simply wrap the "working" method with Anonymous thread and catch the exception as it would be executed without threads.

(The worker's logic was moved from a new class that implemented Callable to the caller class)

```
class BlaBla{

public void foo(){

Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
    doWork();
    } catch (MyCheckedException e) {
      dosomething();
    }
  }
});
th.start();
}

public void dowork throws MyCheckedException{
}
```

Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: The question of whether there's a problem or not depends on what you're trying to achieve. Why did you not wish to catch exceptions in your main thread?

Comment: Yes it's fine or you can use an UncaughtExceptionHandler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409676/829571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work so long as you know what you're doing in those `doWork` and `doSomething` methods.

Is it accessing data that other threads also can access? If so then you should think about protecting that using `synchronized` or some other thread-safe method like message passing between threads using a thread-safe message queue. You'll have to think about what is best to solve your problem.

It would be interesting to know a little bit more about what it's doing because when you wrap it up in a thread you need to think about how to get data to and from that thread in a thread-safe manner. There is probably a simple and safe way to get the job done but it depends on the situation.